# TestNG on Java with Selenium

Tags: java, testng

I've made a simple test on on gradle. Login and four functions:

- send message;
- change language;
- change name, and;
- delete some messages.

Also, four of these tests should start from a certain page. I can't get the `TestNG.xml` file right.

```
public class Test {
@Test(groups = {"T1"}
public void login() {}

@Test(dependsOnGroups = "T1", groups = {"T3"})
public void change_name(){}

@Test(dependsOnGroups = "T1", groups = {"T3"})
public void send_massage(){}

@Test(dependsOnGroups = "T1", groups = {"T3"})
public void find_my_massages(){}

@Test(dependsOnGroups = "T1", groups = {"T3"})
public void change_language(){}
}`
```

My TestNG

```
<suite name="TestYa" parallel="methods">
<test name="Test1 ">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="T1"/>
            <include name="T3"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="Test">
            <methods>
                <include name="find_my_massages"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: What is the issue ? Can you describe it

Comment: I should run all 5 tests correctly, in idea all of them run , but in testng i must start from certain page , how can i start all of them from the same conditions
in testng.xml

Comment: i can give link on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle in TestNG.XML by:

**TestNG.XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="packageName.className(Test)"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**@Test:-**

```
public class Test {
@Test(groups = {"T1"}, priority=1)
public void login() {}

@Test(priority=2)
public void change_name(){}

@Test(priority=3)
public void send_massage(){}

@Test(priority=4)
public void find_my_massages(){}

@Test(priority=5)
public void change_language(){}
}`
```

Like this, You can define Priority of @Test, To execute it by defined order

Comment: and how i return to page after logging?

Comment: i mean , this methods running all after logging ,not one after another

Comment: You can remove this dependsOnGroups = "T1", groups = {"T3"} and add priority on @Test

Comment: and whot to do with ligin test ?

Comment: my tutor talk about basic authentication. He says , that i can get any link on page after logging. Do you know how to do this on chrome on selenium